# Difference Between window.resize() and window.on('resize') in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is difference between `window.resize()` and `window.on('resize' , function())`
in jquery?

Comment: There is no reason why you would use it compared to `on("resize"...`. You might as well do that, just like `click(function()...` works, but it's best to just attach an event handler using `on()` instead.

Comment: @Snorlax "It's best to just...[use] `on()`..."? Why? The former is a short-hand for the latter, and it exists for a reason. It's more readable in many cases, and you write less code for the same effect. It's "best" to do what works for your scenario, and to be aware of the alternatives and their significance. That's the point of this question.

Comment: @nbrooks You might as well do it, because you're going to need it in the future, if you want to attach multiple events. Such as `on("click dragover"` etc. If you want to do something to a dynamically added element, you also need to use it, like this `$("body").on("click", ".dynamicElement", function()...`. Why not use it, when you're going to use it in different scenarios? It's better to use one consistent one then.

Comment: @Snorlax The point that you highlighted is that this API is powerful, and has many uses for many use-cases. You use it a certain way when handling delegated events, just as you use it a certain way when handling multiple events, or custom events. The point to keep in mind is that you use the variant that works for your use-case. For a simple "I just need a click-handler scenario", use `click`. For a delegated-event handler that handles clicks and mouseovers on a certain child...well, if it's more complicated to describe you would expect the code to be more involved. Readability > Dogmatism.

Comment: @nbrooks I understand what you're getting at, but I assure you that in the future, all these shorthands will be deprecated, as there is no need for shorthands, which are shorter by what.. 4-5 characters? Doesn't `$("#element").on("click", function()` look better than `$("#element").click(function()` in terms of readability to you? It surely does to me and many, many others.

Comment: @Snorlax That's a valid theory, and while we're both speculating, I'm fairly certain the jQuery folks won't be deprecating these; that would be somewhat of a major departure from how they've managed that API. I do admit this comes down to personal taste, but I prefer `click` myself. My take on readability is that it's not just about character count, but also the number of logical elements in a statement to think about. Don't get me wrong: `on(event)` is extremely intuitive. I just find it easier to process `target event callback` than `target method event(s) callback`.

Comment: There is no such method [`window.resize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) nor is there a method [`window.on()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window).  Maybe you mean `$(window).resize()` and `$(window).on()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) page .resize():

> This method is a shortcut for .on('resize', handler).

and .on() is:

> The .on() method attaches event handlers to the currently selected
>   set of elements in the jQuery object. As of jQuery 1.7, the .on()
>   method provides all functionality required for attaching event
>   handlers. For help in converting from older jQuery event methods, see
>   .bind(), .delegate(), and .live().

So based on jQuery api description, I think there is no difference it's just a shortcut similar to $.click() and others

Answer (score 3):

There was no difference between `$("#element").resize()` and `$("#element").on('resize' , function())`. The former was a shorthand for the latter. However, as of jQuery 3 the event shorthand is deprecated. This also applies to the following event shorthands: blur, click, focus, focusin, focusout, scroll, dblclick, mousedown, mouseup, mousemove, mouseover, mouseout, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, select, submit, keydown, keypress, keyup, and contextmenu.